# Comment Line in Visual studio (Single line and multiple line)

Tags: javascript, visual-studio

How do I Comment in Visual studio for both single and multiple line commenting

Answer (score 1):

```
 Shift + Alt + A      ->For multiple line comment and uncomment

 Ctrl + /             -> For single line comment and uncomment
```